# Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to

Tags: android, gradle

Создаю абсолютно новый проект в AndroidStudio, он сразу билдится и выдаёт ошибку

> Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set
>   ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to

и два варианта, fix variable and build again и go to file. Если выбираю первый, gradle build tools меняется на 2.0.0-alpha1 и ошибка появляется снова

Искал через гугл, все советуют откатить gradle build tools до 1.5.0, попробовал - результат тот же. Я уже менял и wrapper и перебирал огромное количество версий альфы и беты для gradle build tools - результат один.

Попытался последовать совету и прописать системную переменную ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE, однако не помогло и это, как видите вс прописано правильно (значение брал то, которое предлагала студия)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

build.gradle выглдяит так

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.iam.currencies"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

Всё как и было, только добавлен buildScript c dependencies. В другом проекте все работает с 1.5.0. Подскажите, как можно это вылечить?

Comment: какая версия студии?

Comment: 2.0, только насколько я помню я не из неё обновлялся, а качал как только превью вышло, может это преверсия

Comment: Если вы получаете , что версия 2.0.0 устарела, то уж версия 1.5.0 точно не новее :)

Comment: хм, я до сегодняшнего дня связи не улавливал)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть несколько равнозначных вариантов решения:

1. обновите до последней превью [версию Android Studio](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/recent/androidstudio20preview8available)  - 2.0 PR8
2. В всплывающем окошке с ошибкой нажмите "fix plugin version and sync project"
3. просто укажите версию плагина gradle - 2.0.0-alpha8 (то же сделает и пункт 2 за вас)

   ```
   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha8'
   }
   ```

Первый предпочтительней, так как с апдейтом исправлены и некоторые ошибки (смотрите релиз по ссылке выше).